# Miscellaneous Performance

Tags: c#, memory-management

Is it faster to make a comparison or a cast in C#.Net?
For example:

```
bool? flag = null;    
...    
if(flag == true)... or if((bool)flag)...
```

Also, what is the cost (in memory) of a cast?

Comment: I have to ask... why use a nullable bool?  I've always found that setting my bool to whatever value is 'correct' and then only changing it based on some condition(s) works, and then you avoid this question:  you can simply use "if(flag)"

Comment: I thought that this would be the simplest way to illustrate my question. You are correct though, using just a boolean is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If memory serves the compiler will force you to cast the `bool?` to a `bool` before using it in the if statement.  You might like the null coalesce operator:

```
//If flag == null then return false, otherwise return the value of flag.
if (flag ?? false)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Those translate to roughly the same thing.  Unless you're doing an absurdly large number of such checks, the difference is unnoticable for any practical purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If a null value in flag means "false" I would use the comparison. The cast is a bad idea, beacuse it will throw an exception if flag is null. To be save you have to test for null before the cast. That means you have to do a comparion and a cast instead of a comparion only.

Answer (score -1):

The performance difference is negligible.

Also keep in mind that

```
bool? flag = null;
// ...other code...
if ((bool)flag)
{
}
```

might throw an `InvalidOperationException` if `flag` was not assigned in the code between the variable declaration and the cast.